# RGraph Line Charts

Tags: rgraph

I'm looking for a charting library for web based weather software and one of the criteria is x-axis steps.   In other words I have 5 minute series data but if I plot every five minute along the x axis there are too many labels and they overlap.  Can I step X-axis labels so each hour is only displayed once skipping 11/12 x-axis labels but the series data e.g. temp is plotted for every five minutes.

Is this possible in RGraph?

Thanks for your time answering this question and I look forward to receiving a yes and possibly a how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. So you have (for example) 24 data points - just fewer labels (eg 6). Or you could use a Scatter chart with a connecting line. There's a demo in the download archive:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable

Comment: Cheers Richard,  as soon as I get the data out I'll try it.